# Python code Error : IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x

While am trying to run the Python code given below using Anaconda prompt:

```
python HelloWorld.py
```

**HelloWorld.py**

```
import sys
print("Hello World")
a = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]
c = sys.argv[3]
print("Params ",a,b,c)
```

System throws error:

```
IndexError: List index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass parameters, for an example sys.argv[0] is your python file, if you want to pass parameter, use the following command

```
python HelloWorld.py args1 args2 args3
```